How To Conditionally Set ProgramID in declare_id! macro?
In every Anchor example lib.rs has a hardcoded program id, something like this:
declare_id!("3gHtqUaKGu3RJCWVbgQFd5Gv4MQfQKmQjKSvdejkLoA6");

But I want to have different builds for staging and prod that both deploy to devnet. So I'm trying something like this:
#[cfg(feature = "devnet-staging")]
declare_id!("3gHtqUaKGu3RJCWVbgQFd5Gv4MQfQKmQjKSvdejkLoA7");

#[cfg(feature = "devnet-prod")]
declare_id!("3gHtqUaKGu3RJCWVbgQFd5Gv4MQfQKmQjKSvdejkLoA7");

and try to create variables conditionally:
    #[cfg(feature = "devnet-staging")]
    let env_value: &str = "ye ole' staging";
        
    #[cfg(feature = "devnet-prod")]
    let env_value: &str = "the great prod!";


And I declare the features in Cargo.toml:
[features]
default = []
devnet-staging = []
devnet-prod = []

But then I get errors that these are not found:
error[E0425]: cannot find value `env_value` in this scope
  --> programs/my_project/src/lib.rs:27:62
   |
27 |         msg!("Greetings from: {:?} on {:?}", ctx.program_id, env_value);
   |                                                              ^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

but when I build with cargo build --features devnet-staging I get the error:
Is it even possible to support multiple features in an Anchor project? Why is --features not a flag I can pass to anchor build? How can I use some kind of "environment variables" in my declare_id! block?
Thanks

you're doing it right! The only issue is that you probably want to run cargo build-sbf --features devnet-staging to actually build your program.
